# Fetch API store custom header value for later use

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have the following:

```
let eTag: any 

const request = (method: string) => (basePath: string) => async (path: string, data?: object) => {
  const accessToken = await getAccessToken()
  const opt: any = {
    method,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      ...(data && { eTag })
    },
    ...(data && { body: data }),
  }

  return fetch(`${basePath}${path}`, opt).then(
    res => {
      eTag = res.headers.get('ETag')

      return res.json()
    }
  )
}
```

I have managed to get the value form the customer header `eTag` but it doesn't seem to store it correctly.

I am getting the error of `Unexpected end of JSON input` in regards to `res.json()`

Comment: Could you paste your json as well ?

Answer (score 1):

`res.json()` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). So you need the following:

```
let eTag: any 

const request = (method: string) => (basePath: string) => async (path: string, data?: object) => {
  const accessToken = await getAccessToken()
  const opt: any = {
    method,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      ...(data && { eTag })
    },
    ...(data && { body: data }),
  }

  return fetch(`${basePath}${path}`, opt).then(
    async res => { //add async keyword
      eTag = res.headers.get('ETag')

      return await res.json() //add await here to return resolved json
    }
  )
}
```